# How to convert editable PDF to non-editable PDF in PHP/NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, pdf

**Problem**

I would like to know is there any **PHP/NodeJS API** available to convert editable PDF to non-editable PDF online. We have a client application where we need a scenario where the user downloads the PDF should not able to modify it thought any software (eg. Foxit reader, Adobe)

Basically, we are using [PDF-LIB](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) right now and it seems there is no solution for the non-editable pdf [API to set access privileges](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/443), I have search a lot but does not found any API for that, Am not using the pdf-flatten because we want everything selectable, Appreciate your help.

List of libraries tried and fail to achieve the results

1. [bpampuch/pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) issue [can't load an existing pdf](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/105)
2. [PDF-LIB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib) issue [can't support permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib)
3. [nrhirani/node-qpdf](https://github.com/nrhirani/node-qpdf) issue [File restrictions not working properly](https://github.com/nrhirani/node-qpdf/issues/18)

Comment: If the text is selectable in the PDF and returns valid characters, it can be modified. If you don't want the PDF to be modifiable, you need to convert the pages to images.

As for access privileges: They won't really help you because not all PDF reader applications respect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research work and tried multiple libraries in PHP/Node. I don't found any library that is mature enough to proceed with that, so I decided to make an API that will build in different technology C# and *Java*

**Solution**
we post the PDF URL through API, the API download that file, and apply for multiple permission according to the dataset.

**Library**
the library we choose is [ASPOSE](https://products.aspose.com/pdf)

```
// These can be true/false
config.IsPrint = true;

// Document is allowed to be changed.
config.IsModify = false;

// Annotation is allowed.
config.IsAnnot = true;

// Form filling is allowed.
config.IsFillForm = true;

// Content extraction is allowed.
config.IsExtract = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think flattening the PDF might help you to make it un-editable in case your target is

- Just the form fields then you might use this from the [PDF-LIB](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib#flatten-form) github repo
- The entire PDF then, see if [pdf-flatten](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-flatten) package helps for Node.js

Comment: Hi, will the text is selectable ?

Comment: I haven't used any of these myself , so not quite sure about it, but as flattening converts to image, most probably it might become unselectable, however you can go ahead and do a test run and confirm the same.

Comment: Yes I've been checked that's why not used a flatter pattren